# Regex assistance to a newbie

Tags: php, regex

Here's my code:

```
$searchTerm='/9j/4AAQSkZJ';
$searchTerm = preg_replace('/\/(+s)\//i','',$searchTerm);
```

I'm trying to remove `/9j/` from the `$searchTerm`.

**It's specifically a slash then a set of characters and integers without spaces then a slash**

what is not right about my expression?

Comment: It will make it easier to read if you use something like #'s for your regex delimiters (ie. `#/(+s)/#i`)

Comment: @AlexGittemeier I'm sorry, Im still a newbie at regex. my expression escapes the /, so why would i put a # sign there when i need to fix that specific pattern?

Comment: what about http://regexr.com?35obj ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `+s` with `.*`

Also, no need for the `i`

```
$newTerm = preg_replace('/\/(.*)\//', '', $searchTerm);
```

Tested here: http://regexpfiddle.com/

Comment: +1 from nice answer and to provide the fast solution and solution from the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
$newTerm = preg_replace('#/[a-z0-9]+/#i', '', $searchTerm);
```

Replacing the `/` delimiters with something else (`#` in my example) just makes it easier to read, especially if your pattern happens to contain `/` characters. Using another delimiter means you don't need to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got `+s` from as anything meaningful in regex.

Personally I'd suggest this:

```
$searchTerm = explode("/",$searchTerm,3)[2];
```

But note that this only works in up-to-date PHP. For older versions, you'd need:

```
$searchTerm = explode("/",$searchTerm,3);
$searchTerm = $searchTerm[2];
```

If you want a regex, try this:

```
$searchTerm = preg_replace("(^/[^/]+/)","",$searchTerm);
```

This regex uses parentheses as delimiters (you never have to escape anything to avoid conflict if you use parentheses, because they come in matched pairs), and it starts from the beginning of the string, looks for a slash, then anything that's not a slash, then a second slash, and removes it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different delimiter:

```
preg_replace('~/\w+/~','',$term);
```

Comment: Careful, `\w` matches more than just *"a set of characters and integers without spaces"*

Comment: Right, it matches underscores too. I don't know what `(+s)` was supposed to mean.

Comment: I'm guessing it was meant to be `\S+`

Comment: @Phil I think that `\S` stands for everything except a space (any type of space), including `/` which might be problematic with a different input and lazy/greedy evaluation mode (`U`). But I'm not mastering regex so I might be wrong (please correct me if I am!). That's also why I like your answer better than using `\S` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('#/.*/#', '', $searchTerm);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchTerm='/9j/4AAQSkZJ';
$searchTerm = preg_replace('~^/\S+/~','',$searchTerm);
```